# Authenticate MVC application with both Windows live ID and Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-acs

I have developed MVC 5 application. Now i want to use Authentication for my application.
My end users are Employees and Customers and i want to authenticate Employees with Azure AD and customers with windows live id.

I have tried to use Azure ACS, but it will ask me whether i want to log in with Azure AD or Windows Live ID.

My requirement is as below.
Default URL is http://localhost:12973.
When Employees want to login then it will redirect to http://localhost:12973/employees and employees should redirect to Azure AD log in page
and for customers http://localhost:12973/customers and customers should be redirected to windows log in page

So how can i configure both Azure AD and ACS in single web config file?

Can anyone please help me how can i achieve both the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup Azure AD as an IdP for ACS to utilise and then switch your MVC app to only use ACS.  Details on how to setup Azure AD as an ACS identity source can be [found on Vittorio's blog](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2012/11/07/PROVISIONING-A-DIRECTORY-TENANT-AS-AN-IDENTITY-PROVIDER-IN-AN-ACS-NAMESPACE/).

In order to differentiate between the user types you would have to inspect the incoming claims and determine whether the user is in Azure AD (I assume employee) or elsewhere (customer). That would be your 'return URL' which would then do a 301 redirect to the correct landing page as per your requirements.

In the future Azure AD will be the right place to do all this stuff (including external IDs) so it might be worth revisiting your design and reading some of the recent advice around how to use Azure AD instead of ACS.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively your application can trust Auth0 and you can configure Microsoft Accounts (Windows Live) and Azure AD as connections in Auth0. The [following sample](https://auth0.com/docs/scenarios/multi-tenant-saas-azure-ad) shows how to use Azure AD with different social connections:

[image: Sample]

The big difference with ACS today is that Auth0 can also get the email address of users authenticating with a Microsoft Account.

**Disclaimer**: I work for Auth0.

Comment: I get a 404 when opening the link. Can you put a correct link to the sample?